# C/Unix Strange behaviour while using system calls and printf

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I'm a newbie, trying to *really* understand systems programming. In the following program, I'm reading a file called 'temp1' (containing 1 2 3 4) and printing its contents to stdout. However, I also wanted to check the value of file descriptor returned by open. If I include the '\n' in printf call on line 5, the output prints value filep first and then contents of file. But if I remove the newline, the contents of file get printed first and then the value of filep.
Why would this happen ?

```
     int main(){
     char buf[BUFSIZ];
     int n, filep;

     // Open the file
     filep = open("temp1", 'r');
     printf("%d\n", filep); // the newline alters program behaviour

     while((n=read(filep, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
         write(1, buf, n);
     return 0;
    }
```

I am using gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan : ?? open syscall returns a file descriptor, which is an integer. The printf prints the value of that file descriptor.

Comment: Yes you are correct! ... consider second point of my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<stdio.h>` functions like `printf` are *buffered*. Output functions will call the `write(2)` syscall only from time to time, usually output functions like `printf` etc... are going only into the internal `FILE` buffer.

The `stdout` is line-buffered when outputting to a terminal (see [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)). So if a `printf` format string ends with `\n` the write will occur.

You could add a `fflush(stdout);` or `fflush(NULL);` call before your `while` loop.

See [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) and [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html)

If you don't flush `stdout` (either with a `\n` in printf format string, or explicitly thru `fflush` or `fclose`) the buffer is flushed only at the end of `main` (thru some implicit [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) ...)

So what is happening to you is that (without the `\n`) data stays in the `stdout` buffer, and is actually written (by the `write(2)` inside `stdio` library) only at the exit of your program.

Read [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com).

Comment: @ Basile : Thanks. I got it from your extended answer. Great explanation.